# How to reuse Django tests?

Tags: django

I'm extending Django `QuerySet` by subclass (say `MyQuerySet`), and I would like to guarantee that my implementation does not break any existing functionality of `QuerySet`.

How can I test `MyQuerySet` against existing Django tests on `QuerySet` without having to replicate them?

For concreteness, let's consider the example of tests of `prefetch_related`, found in `django/tests/prefetch_related` package.

I would like to run all those tests on `MyQuerySet`. However, those tests are implemented using the default manager of the models in the package. Does anyone have any idea how to e.g. duck type `objects` to a custom manager that uses `MyQuerySet`?